# C#: Is there a way to define method array parameter of an unkown rank?

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I'd like to define a method that accepts an array as a parameter, but this array may be of any rank. The rank will be specified by a separate parameter. Something to replace/generalize the following:

```
// one dimensional array
public void WorkOnJaggedArray<T>(int rank, int[] dimensions, T[] data) 
{
     /* code */
}

// two dimensional array
public void WorkOnJaggedArray<T>(int rank, int[] dimensions, T[][] data) 
{
     /* code */
}

// three dimensional array
public void WorkOnJaggedArray<T>(int rank, int[] dimensions, T[][][] data) 
{
     /* code */
}

// and so on...
```

Given that I have the rank and the size of each dimension passed in, I should be able to generalize the code inside my method. Is there a good way to achieve what I'm asking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I simplified my question here, but this is going to be part of a larger API and `data` needs to be passed in like that.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you not use `params`?

Comment: It is not clear to me how `params` could be used here for my problem. The caller of the method needs to send in one *jagged array* not a variable list of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "System.Array" to manage parameters of any rank :

Create your array instance by calling Array.CreateInstance.

This will give you an instance of the Array class.
Call SetValue to assign values to your array.
Use GetValue to retrieve any elements of the array.

```
     public void WorkOnJaggedArray<T>(int rank, int[] dimensions, Array data) 
{
     /* code */
}
```

Comment: My problem is not determining the dimension of the array. My problem is defining a general method parameter.

Comment: @mbadawi23: with this method signature you can pass in a `string[]` or a `string[][]` or any other array like thing you want to. If you know the rank of the array then your code can use that to extract the appropriate data. Oh, though I notice this was recently edited and the old answer wasn't as helpful. But yes, this should do the job now. :)